# How to resolve issues in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, sdk, android-virtual-device

I am new to coding and Android development,I am learning from course offered by META on Coursera. I opened a new project and tried to download SDK and creating new virtual device. But I am getting "Tag mismatch error" while doing this process and even I am getting the same error when I opened build section.
**error in build section**
[image: error in build section]

**error when tried to download SDK**
[image: error when tried to download SDK]

I tried checking XML and reformatted XML file as suggested by ChatGPT.

Comment: Jut a heads up since you're new to coding - ChatGPT doesn't understand anything, it's sheer luck if it gives you something useful or just wastes your time with inaccurate or completely irrelevant info (like whatever you did with an XML file there)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, error, logs, or other text; see [ask].